# What can I do to generate the DB in EF Code First?

Tags: wpf, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce-4

I am not planning to use EF Code First in an MVC Website. I am looking to Utilize it in a App that has a WPF Client.

Projects are setup as

- ContactManager.Core // Contains all
  Entities(dll)
- ContactManager.Data //    Contains
  the  DataContext and other    data
  related Services(dll)
- ContactManager.Services // Business
  components (dll)
- ContactManager.Client // WPF
  Application

I am unable to generate a SQLExpress or SQLCE 4.0 DB. I am more interested in compact version db. I am not getting any error except my unit tests fail because it tries to connect a db that doesnt exist.

Comment: I've you found an answer to this question? I'm trying to do same here!

Comment: @GabrielMongeon: I havent found a way to do this..

Comment: I manage to make it work with SQLExpress with this walkthrough: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-model-with-master-detail-wpf-application.aspx. Now I'll figure out what is needed to make it work with SQLCE, I'm guessing something in the App.Config should do the trick. I'll keep you posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer 2 Options:

**Option 1:**

In your DbContext you specify the connection strings in the base constructor:

```
public class RecetteContext : DbContext
{
    public RecetteContext()
        :base("<YourConnectionString HERE>")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Categorie> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recette> Recettes { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

The one I used, you give you connection string a name in the DbContext base constructor:

```
public RecetteContext()
    : base("RecettesDatabase")
{            }
```

And in your App.Config file you add a ConnectionString with the same name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RecettesDatabase"
         connectionString="Data Source=RecettesDB.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Hope it solved your issue!